# OpenGL Framebuffer ColorAttachment to Compute Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, framebuffer

I want to put the Color Attachment of my custom framebuffer into a compute shader for simple image processing, but I am getting a black screen only.
Here is my example code

Creating color attachment

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &this->fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this->fbo);
glGenTextures(1, &this->textureColorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textureColorBuffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, this->width(), this->height(), 0, 
GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
this->textureColorBuffer, 0);
```

Compiling and linking shader

```
cshader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
const char *csSrc[] = {
    "#version 440\n",
    "layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D destTex;\
     layout (binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform image2D sourceTex;\
     layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;\
     void main() {\              
            vec4 texel;\
            ivec2 storePos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);\
            texel = imageLoad(sourceTex, storePos);\
            texel = vec4(1.0) - texel;\
            imageStore(destTex, storePos, texel);\
    }"
};
glShaderSource(cshader, 2, csSrc, NULL);
glCompileShader(cshader);


cshaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(cshaderprogram, cshader);
glLinkProgram(cshaderprogram);
```

Invoke Shader and drawing texture to quad. The shader is a simple color switching shader, for testing purposes.

```
glUseProgram(cshaderprogram);
glUniform1i(0, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindImageTexture(0, outputTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, 
GL_RGBA32F);


glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindImageTexture(0, textureColorBuffer, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, 
GL_RGBA32F);
glUniform1i(1, 1);
glDispatchCompute(width() / 16, height() / 16, 1);

glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
screenProgram.bind();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(screenVao);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

I am able to render the textureColorBuffer to the quad correctly and i can write to a texture. I think the problem that i do not know how to read from the framebuffer.

I hope you can help me. If there are still some questions just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding point of `sourceTex` is 1 and not 0:

```
layout (binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform image2D sourceTex;
```

So you have to bind the texture to the image unit 1

```
glBindImageTexture( 1, // <------- 1 instead of 0
    textureColorBuffer, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
```

Note, [Images units](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Overview) and [Texture units](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units) are different things.

---

Of course you can use a texture sampler uniform in the coumpute shader too. If `destTex` and `sourceTex` have the same size, you can use [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml) with `gl_GlobalInvocationID`, to look up `sourceTex`:

```
layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D destTex;
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D sourceTex; 

void main()
{       
    ivec2 pos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);       

    vec4 texel = texelFetch(sourceTex, pos, 0);

    texel = vec4(1.0) - texel;
    imageStore(destTex, pos, texel);
}
```

In the above snippet is used the image unit 0 for `destTex` and the texture unit 0 for `sourceTex`.

---

By the way, are you sure that you want to do

```
texel = vec4(1.0) - texel;
```

Note, if the alpha channel of `texel` is 1.0, it will become completely transparent.

Comment: Absolutely great help again. Its working now. I made some little mistakes and you showed and explained me ho to solve this. thank you!